# Loopj Android Asynchronous Http Client Cookies not save in signed apk

Tags: android, cookies, google-play, loopj

Why my cookies are not saved when my app is exported with signed certificate for upload to Google Play Store?

When I run my app in from eclipse it works fine and the cookies are saved.

I use for **Http connection** with this library:

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

**and with this method:**

```
mClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
mClient.setCookieStore(new PersistentCookieStore(context));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a loopj bug !!

I had to comment this line in my **project.properties** file:
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

Also read at:
https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/688